# Replace redundant Code with SP / UDF

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I have code:

```
SELECT Date
,trafficsource
INTO #temp
FROM SomeTable;
```

That is the first step. The second step is the following code:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.DimTrafficSource ( TrafficSource, LogInsert )
SELECT DISTINCT fact.trafficSource
,GETDATE()
FROM #temp fact
LEFT JOIN dbo.DimTrafficSource dim ON fact.trafficSource = dim.TrafficSource
WHERE dim.TrafficSource IS NULL
```

Now, the second step is used in many other stored procedures. To avoid using the same "`hardcoded`" code in them, I'd prefer to replace this functionality with other function / stored procedure so when I want to modify the logic, I want to modify it at one place, not in every stored procedure using this code. Is it possible when there is a temp table used? How?

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for a *view*

Comment: Or you can replace INSERT with MERGE

Comment: Hmm, the view could be the way. Would you have maybe example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can. If you switch from a local to a [global temp table](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979.aspx) (## instead of #) it will be available to all SPs you create.  The example below demonstrates this.

However I would recommend you switch to regular table.  Temp tables can be hard to debug and track.  It is not always obvious when they do/don't exist.

Example

```
/* Temp procedure 1 creates a
 * global temp table.
 */
CREATE PROCEDURE #Temp1 AS
BEGIN
    SELECT
        1 AS x
    INTO 
        ##tempT
    ;
END
GO

/* Temp procedure 2 
 * can access the temp table..
 */
CREATE PROCEDURE #Temp2 AS
BEGIN
    SELECT
        x
    FROM
        ##tempT
    ;
END
GO


/* Excecuting the SPs
 * show the temp table is shared.
 */
EXECUTE #Temp1;
EXECUTE #Temp2;
```

Comment: Thanks. Plus there should be also code for droping those tables once load is done, shouldnt it?

Comment: From MSDN:  Global temporary tables are automatically dropped when the session that created the table ends and all other tasks have stopped referencing them. The association between a task and a table is maintained only for the life of a single Transact-SQL statement. This means that a global temporary table is dropped at the completion of the last Transact-SQL statement that was actively referencing the table when the creating session ended.